# SQL Server -XML nodes not returning multiple records

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm trying to get my head round SQL, XML nodes and Cross apply, i would have thought that the following code would return 3 rows of data but instead i only get one. i had thought that using Cross apply to join the query back onto itself would solve this for me.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Dan

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML;

SELECT @XML = ('<Deal deal_id="821">
  <Application_owner>me</Application_owner>
   <Deal_files>
    <File>file1.doc</File>
    <File>file2.pdf</File>
    <File>file3.xcl</File>
  </Deal_files>
</Deal>
')

select 
    t.n.value('@deal_id', 'int') as [ID],
    f.n.value('(File)[1]','varchar(50)') as [FILENAME]
from 
    @XML.nodes('Deal') t(n)
cross apply 
    t.n.nodes('Deal_files') f(n)
```

Comment: `t.n.nodes('Deal_files')` only matches one element, so you'll only get one SQL row from it (which will contain 3 XML elements/rows).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML;

SELECT @XML = ('<Deal deal_id="821">
  <Application_owner>me</Application_owner>
   <Deal_files>
    <File>file1.doc</File>
    <File>file2.pdf</File>
    <File>file3.xcl</File>
  </Deal_files>
</Deal>
'
)

Select 
    ID = t.n.value('@deal_id', 'int'),
    FileName = f.n.value('(.)[1]','varchar(50)') 
From  
    @XML.nodes('Deal') t(n)
Cross Apply 
    t.n.nodes('Deal_files/*') f(n)
```

Returns

```
ID  FileName
--------------
821 file1.doc
821 file2.pdf
821 file3.xcl
```

Comment: Hi, let me be a little picky: `t.n.nodes('Deal_files/*')` should be `t.n.nodes('Deal_files/File')` just to make sure not to return other nodes... +1 from my side

Comment: Thank you for the answer . if i understand this correctly my mistake was to  name  the element rather than use "." which in this instance wouldn't bring back multiple rows because there was only one 'Deal_files'?

Comment: @Dan Happy it helped and yes you are correct regarding the name vs "."